# What are uses for lemongrass seeds

Tags: seeds, herbs

We have a huge lemongrass bush that went to seed. Before triming and harvesting the leaves and stalks I cut off and bagged all of the seeds. Now i have a couple pounds of seeds. I find nothing anywhere about using lemongrass seeds for anything other than planting more lemongrass.

Are there any other safe uses for lemongrass seeds? Seasoning? Tea? Repellant for skin or on leaves of other plants?

While researching it seems seeds are usually sold by the "each" unit, like 100 for $2.50. I must have a million seeds in this bag. Am I suddenly rich? :) How are lemongrass seeds counted for sale? And still related to my main question, should I process this for sale?

Thanks

Comment: why did you save the seeds if you don't have a use for them?  How long would it take you to count, pack, ship, and oversee a packet you can only make $2 (after tax) from? if you want to make $15/hr, it better take less than 7 mins on avg.

Comment: it might be worth contacting local seedbanks or garden clubs or nurseries and making a few bucks for a bunch of seeds. That's a lot less effort/risk than going wholesale overnight.

Comment: I bagged them in anticipation of asking this question. I could have trashed them, asked this question afterward, only to find someone who asks "that was a few hundred dollars worth of seeds, why did you trash them?!" :)

Comment: ha, that always happens to me. it a fun thought but i don't think the numbers are there for you to get rich.

Comment: That's fine. I'm hoping someone can provide info about uses other than just planting more lemongrass, like tea, seasoning, sachets, whatever. It's the mysterious lack of info on this topic that prompted me to post here. Thanks for the comments.